# PowerShell Team foundation server 2017

Tags: powershell, tfs

Does anyone know what happened to the Powershell power tools for TFS 2017?

I have existing scripts for TFS and would like to keep using them.

I tried installed the 2015 tools but they will not install because it requires VS 2015 and I am using 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge there are no Power Tools for Team Foundation Server 2017 (see https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2017-relnotes).

That said you can leverage @igor-abade Powershell CmdLets (https://github.com/igoravl/tfscmdlets) which offer a good deal of features.

Comment: tfscmdlets isn't hard to get working, but it doesn't seem to work with the new non-xaml builds. I wanted to queue builds with it, and it doesn't look that will work.